# electrons inside nucleus and uncertainty principle

Tags: speed-of-light, nuclear-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

> State the assumptions of the proton-electron model of the nucleus. Show that if one uses the Heisenberg uncertainty relation to estimate the speed of an electron inside a nucleus with a diameter of approximately 5 fm, the result is a speed exceeding that of light.

Now my solution is
[image]

Is that right ??

Comment: If the electron is going to be faster than light I suspect you should probably use the full relativistic form for momentum $\gamma mv$ or better yet kinetic energy $\left(\gamma -1 \right)mc^2=\frac{p^2}{2m}$ to get the speed.

Comment: It can't be said if your calculus is correct before we know whether you are supposed to use for the linear momentum the Newtonian formula, or the relativistic formula. You'd better ask your instructor. I did the calculus with the relativistic formula and one gets that the electron should have the light velocity. Indeed, if the electron is suspected to have velocity > c, which is non-physical, the relativity should be used, so, the question seems wrong.

Comment: @Chris2807, I used relativistic form of $p$ but the result is what Sofia said..

Comment: Could you give some more detail about this model? It's not something I am very familiar with

Comment: @Chris2807, $1.5457\times 10^{-20}=\frac{9.10938291\times 10^{-31}v}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{2.99\times 10^{8}}}}$
$\Rightarrow v^2=\frac{\left(1.5457\times 10^{-20}\right)^2}{m^2+\left(\frac{1.5457\times 10^{-20}}{c}\right)^2}$
$\Rightarrow v\approx2.989535902\times 10^{8}m/s$ the result is less than speed of light !

Comment: @Sofia if you use relativistic momentum formula, you can't ever get $v>c$. So it's obvious that one is supposed to use Newtonian one.

Comment: Sorry in my previous comment I meant explain a little bit more about the proton-electron model of the nucleus, I have never heard of this.

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have very likely done what the teacher wanted you to do. But you should maybe mention to teacher that he has asked a poor question (actually... maybe you shouldn't mention it... or at least be diplomatic about it...)

The reason the question is dumb is because, as pointed out in the comments, you could (reasonably) use the relativistic expression for "p" in terms of "v". But, clearly, if you use the relativistic formula for "p" in terms of "v", you are always going to get a velocity less that the speed of light... Because  no matter how big "p" is, there is no way to get v>c with the relativistic formula.